# How to plot increment groups from a list?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I have a list of 2250 keys. I want to lots groups of 450 keys, moving through the list.

I want to plot this as a graph in pandas - with a plot line for the first 450 keys, next 450, and so on till the last 1800-2250 keys.

I have the following code:

```
x = x.sort_values(ascending=False)
c = seq_col_brew = sns.color_palette("Blues_r")
fig,ax = plt.subplots(figsize=[10,5])
for n,i in enumerate(range(0,len(x), 450)):
    ids = x[i:i+450].index
    sns.tsplot([dict[k] for k in ids],time=xticks,color=c[n])
    sns.plt.title('rank in 450 increments',fontsize=20) 
    sns.plt.legend(['rank 1-450',\
            'rank 450-900',\
            'rank 1350-1800',\
            'rank 1800-2250'])
```

However, I cannot seem to work out why pandas plots 5 lines on the graph, not 4. I am relatively new to python, but trying learn via stacked overflow.

X (sorted) looks like this:

```
loc.3    91.299578
loc.9    90.333623
loc.2    89.247350
loc.234    89.225299
loc.188    89.213507
.....
loc.277  50.1240083
```

Comment: Can you add sample of `x`

Comment: Ive added a sample of x

Comment: No, what this means is that you should provide a [mcve]. I.e. a code that lets others reproduce the issue.

Comment: (1) You can't use `dict[k]` unless you've defined a variable named `dict`, which you shouldn't do in the first place, but which also isn't shown here. (2) `xticks` is not shown. (3) Why do you think there should be 4 and not 5 lines?  What are the 4 lines?  Show your expected output and the current graph that is being generated.  (4) Even better, include a proper [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).